# bind multiple inputs to each other in vuejs to change together

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i want multiple text inputs that when i change one of them i want  others to change with the same value too . my inputs are generating in a loop of v-for like below :

```
  <tbody>
<variant-item v-for='(variant, index) in variants' :variant="variant" :key="index" :index="index" "></variant-item>
 </tbody>
```

and here the input is getting generated :

```
<td>
   <div class="control-group" :class="[errors.has(variantInputName + '[price]') ? 'has-error' : '']">
   <input type="number" v-model="variant.price" :name="[variantInputName + '[price]']" />
   <span class="control-error" v-if="errors.has(variantInputName + '[price]')">@{{ errors.first(variantInputName + '[price]') }}</span></div>
</td>
```

so with this code if i have 2 products for example the result would be like below :

```
<td><div class="control-group"><input type="number" name="variants[4344][price]" data-vv-as="&quot;price&quot;" step="any" class="control"> <!----></div></td>

.
.
.
.
<td><div class="control-group"><input type="number" name="variants[4345][price]" data-vv-as="&quot;[price&quot;" > <!----></div></td>
```

now I want this 2 or multiple inputs change together .

```
@section('css')
    @parent
    <style>
        .table th.price, .table th.weight {
            width: 100px;
        }
        .table th.actions {
            width: 85px;
        }
        .table td.actions .icon {
            margin-top: 8px;
        }
        .table td.actions .icon.pencil-lg-icon {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
    </style>
@stop

{!! view_render_event('bagisto.admin.catalog.product.edit_form_accordian.variations.before', ['product' => $product]) !!}

<accordian :title="'{{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.variations') }}'" :active="true">
    <div slot="body">

        {!! view_render_event('bagisto.admin.catalog.product.edit_form_accordian.variations.controls.before', ['product' => $product]) !!}

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" @click="showModal('addVariant')">
            {{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.add-variant-btn-title') }}
        </button>

        <variant-list></variant-list>

        {!! view_render_event('bagisto.admin.catalog.product.edit_form_accordian.variations.controls.after', ['product' => $product]) !!}

    </div>
</accordian>

{!! view_render_event('bagisto.admin.catalog.product.edit_form_accordian.variations.after', ['product' => $product]) !!}

<modal id="addVariant" :is-open="modalIds.addVariant">
    <h3 slot="header">{{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.add-variant-title') }}</h3>

    <div slot="body">
        <variant-form></variant-form>
    </div>
</modal>

@push('scripts')
    @parent

    <script type="text/x-template" id="variant-form-template">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.catalog.products.store') }}" data-vv-scope="add-variant-form" @submit.prevent="addVariant('add-variant-form')">

            <div class="page-content">
                <div class="form-container">

                    <div v-for='(attribute, index) in super_attributes' class="control-group" :class="[errors.has('add-variant-form.' + attribute.code) ? 'has-error' : '']">
                        <label :for="attribute.code" class="required">@{{ attribute.admin_name }}</label>
                        <select v-validate="'required'" v-model="variant[attribute.code]" class="control" :id="attribute.code" :name="attribute.code" :data-vv-as="'&quot;' + attribute.admin_name + '&quot;'">
                            <option v-for='(option, index) in attribute.options' :value="option.id">@{{ option.admin_name }}</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="control-error" v-if="errors.has('add-variant-form.' + attribute.code)">@{{ errors.first('add-variant-form.' + attribute.code) }}</span>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                        {{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.add-variant-title') }}
                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-template" id="variant-list-template">
        <div class="table" style="margin-top: 20px; overflow-x: auto;">
            <table>

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="sku">{{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.sku') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.name') }}</th>

                        @foreach ($product->super_attributes as $attribute)
                            <th class="{{ $attribute->code }}" style="width: 150px">{{ $attribute->admin_name }}</th>
                        @endforeach

                        <th class="qty">{{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.qty') }}</th>
                        <th class="price">{{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.price') }}</th>
                        <th class="weight">{{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.weight') }}</th>
                        <th class="status">{{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.status') }}</th>
                        <th class="actions"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                    <variant-item v-for='(variant, index) in variants' :variant="variant" :key="index" :index="index" :variant-price.sync="variantPrice" @onRemoveVariant="removeVariant($event)"></variant-item>

                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-template" id="variant-item-template">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="control-group" :class="[errors.has(variantInputName + '[sku]') ? 'has-error' : '']">
                    <input type="text" v-validate="'required'" v-model="variant.sku" :name="[variantInputName + '[sku]']" class="control" data-vv-as="&quot;{{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.sku') }}&quot;" v-slugify/>
                    <span class="control-error" v-if="errors.has(variantInputName + '[sku]')">@{{ errors.first(variantInputName + '[sku]') }}</span>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="control-group" :class="[errors.has(variantInputName + '[name]') ? 'has-error' : '']">
                    <input type="text" v-validate="'required'" v-model="variant.name"  :name="[variantInputName + '[name]']" class="control" data-vv-as="&quot;{{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.name') }}&quot;"/>
                    <span class="control-error" v-if="errors.has(variantInputName + '[name]')">@{{ errors.first(variantInputName + '[name]') }}</span>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td v-for='(attribute, index) in superAttributes'>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <input type="hidden" :name="[variantInputName + '[' + attribute.code + ']']" :value="variant[attribute.code]"/>
                    <input type="text" class="control" :value="optionName(variant[attribute.code])" readonly/>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <button style="width: 100%;" type="button" class="dropdown-btn dropdown-toggle">
                    @{{ totalQty }}
                    <i class="icon arrow-down-icon"></i>
                </button>

                <div class="dropdown-list">
                    <div class="dropdown-container">
                        <ul>
                            <li v-for='(inventorySource, index) in inventorySources'>
                                <div class="control-group" :class="[errors.has(variantInputName + '[inventories][' + inventorySource.id + ']') ? 'has-error' : '']">
                                    <label>@{{ inventorySource.name }}</label>
                                    <input type="text" v-validate="'numeric|min:0'" :name="[variantInputName + '[inventories][' + inventorySource.id + ']']" v-model="inventories[inventorySource.id]" class="control" v-on:keyup="updateTotalQty()" :data-vv-as="'&quot;' + inventorySource.name  + '&quot;'"/>
                                    <span class="control-error" v-if="errors.has(variantInputName + '[inventories][' + inventorySource.id + ']')">@{{ errors.first(variantInputName + '[inventories][' + inventorySource.id + ']') }}</span>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="control-group" :class="[errors.has(variantInputName + '[price]') ? 'has-error' : '']">
                    <input type="number" v-validate="'required|min_value:0.0001'" v-model="variant.price" :name="[variantInputName + '[price]']" class="control" data-vv-as="&quot;{{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.price') }}&quot;" step="any"/>
                    <span class="control-error" v-if="errors.has(variantInputName + '[price]')">@{{ errors.first(variantInputName + '[price]') }}</span>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="control-group" :class="[errors.has(variantInputName + '[weight]') ? 'has-error' : '']">
                    <input type="number" v-validate="'required|min_value:0.0001'" v-model="variant.weight"  :name="[variantInputName + '[weight]']" class="control" data-vv-as="&quot;{{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.weight') }}&quot;" step="any"/>
                    <span class="control-error" v-if="errors.has(variantInputName + '[weight]')">@{{ errors.first(variantInputName + '[weight]') }}</span>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <select type="text" v-model="variant.status" :name="[variantInputName + '[status]']" class="control">
                        <option value="1" :selected="variant.status">{{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.enabled') }}</option>
                        <option value="0" :selected="!variant.status">{{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.disabled') }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td class="actions">
                <a :href="['{{ route('admin.catalog.products.index') }}/edit/' + variant.id]"><i class="icon pencil-lg-icon"></i></a>
                <i class="icon remove-icon" @click="removeVariant()"></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
                'variant-form',
                'variant-list',
                'variant-item'
            ];
        });

        var super_attributes = @json(app('\Webkul\Product\Repositories\ProductRepository')->getSuperAttributes($product));
        var variants = @json($product->variants);

        Vue.component('variant-form', {

            data: function() {
                return {
                    variant: {},
                    super_attributes: super_attributes
                }
            },

            template: '#variant-form-template',

            created: function () {
                this.resetModel();
            },

            methods: {
                addVariant: function (formScope) {
                    this.$validator.validateAll(formScope).then((result) => {
                        if (result) {
                            var this_this = this;

                            var filteredVariants = variants.filter(function(variant) {
                                var matchCount = 0;

                                for (var key in this_this.variant) {
                                    if (variant[key] == this_this.variant[key]) {
                                        matchCount++;
                                    }
                                }

                                return matchCount == this_this.super_attributes.length;
                            })

                            if (filteredVariants.length) {
                                this.$parent.closeModal();

                                window.flashMessages = [{'type': 'alert-error', 'message': "{{ __('admin::app.catalog.products.variant-already-exist-message') }}" }];

                                this.$root.addFlashMessages()
                            } else {
                                var optionIds = [];
                                for (var key in this_this.variant) {
                                    optionIds.push(this_this.variant[key]);
                                }

                                variants.push(Object.assign({
                                        sku: '{{ $product->sku }}' + '-variant-' + optionIds.join('-'),
                                        name: '',
                                        price: 0,
                                        weight: 0,
                                        status: 1
                                    }, this.variant));

                                this.resetModel();

                                this.$parent.closeModal();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                },

                resetModel: function () {
                    var this_this = this;

                    this.super_attributes.forEach(function(attribute) {
                        this_this.variant[attribute.code] = '';
                    })
                }
            }
        });

        Vue.component('variant-list', {

            template: '#variant-list-template',

            inject: ['$validator'],

            data: function() {
                return {
                    variants: variants,
                    variantPrice:0,
                    old_variants: @json(old('variants')),

                    superAttributes: super_attributes
                }
            },

            created: function () {
                var index = 0;

                for (var key in this.old_variants) {
                    var variant = this.old_variants[key];

                    if (key.indexOf('variant_') !== -1) {
                        var inventories = [];

                        for (var inventorySourceId in variant['inventories']) {
                            inventories.push({'qty': variant['inventories'][inventorySourceId], 'inventory_source_id': inventorySourceId})
                        }

                        variant['inventories'] = inventories;

                        variants.push(variant);
                    } else {
                        for (var code in variant) {
                            if (code != 'inventories') {
                                variants[index][code] = variant[code];
                            } else {
                                variants[index][code] = [];

                                for (var inventorySourceId in variant[code]) {
                                    variants[index][code].push({'qty': variant[code][inventorySourceId], 'inventory_source_id': inventorySourceId})
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    index++;
                }
            },

            methods: {
                removeVariant: function(variant) {
                    let index = this.variants.indexOf(variant)

                    this.variants.splice(index, 1)
                },
            }

        });

        Vue.component('variant-item', {

            template: '#variant-item-template',

            props: ['variantPrice','index', 'variant'],

            inject: ['$validator'],

            data: function() {
                return {
                    inventorySources: @json($inventorySources),
                    inventories: {},
                    totalQty: 0,
                    superAttributes: super_attributes
                }
            },

            created: function () {
                var this_this = this;

                this.inventorySources.forEach(function(inventorySource) {
                    this_this.inventories[inventorySource.id] = this_this.sourceInventoryQty(inventorySource.id)
                    this_this.totalQty += parseInt(this_this.inventories[inventorySource.id]);
                })
            },

            computed: {
                variantInputName: function () {
                    if (this.variant.id)
                        return "variants[" + this.variant.id + "]";

                    return "variants[variant_" + this.index + "]";
                }
            },

            methods: {

                removeVariant: function () {
                    this.$emit('onRemoveVariant', this.variant)
                },
                onVariantPriceInput(event) {
                    this.$emit('update:variantPrice', Number(event.target.value));
                },
                optionName: function (optionId) {
                    var optionName = '';

                    this.superAttributes.forEach(function(attribute) {
                        attribute.options.forEach(function(option) {
                            if (optionId == option.id) {
                                optionName = option.admin_name;
                            }
                        });
                    })

                    return optionName;
                },

                sourceInventoryQty: function (inventorySourceId) {
                    if (! Array.isArray(this.variant.inventories))
                        return 0;

                    var inventories = this.variant.inventories.filter(function(inventory) {
                        return inventorySourceId === parseInt(inventory.inventory_source_id);
                    })

                    if (inventories.length)
                        return inventories[0]['qty'];

                    return 0;
                },

                updateTotalQty: function () {
                    this.totalQty = 0;

                    for (var key in this.inventories) {
                        this.totalQty += parseInt(this.inventories[key]);
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you provided a simplified example of what you are trying to do. There is a lot of extra stuff here which may be necessary for the app, but is just clutter when it comes to this specific problem. If I wanted to create a prototype to reproduce your problem, I would need to remove all of the vee-validate cruft. Also, what is the `variant-item` custom component? I think you could reduce the example code to what is necessary to demonstrate the problem. This may even help you solve it on your own.

Comment: yes `variant-item` is my vue component and yes you are right i just guessed that this may help i will edit it

Comment: extra info removed

Comment: I don't understand if _all_ variants are to share a single `price` or if each is to have its own `price`.

Comment: they all have to share the same price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is your objective to have a single price which is shared by all variants, then I would advise against having a `price` property per `variant` Object. `variant.price` suggests a price *per* variant. I would create a separate data property, say `variantPrice` that would be passed to each instance of the `variant-item` component.

(As an aside: If there is a single price that is to be shared by all `variant-item` components then it may be confusing to your users that you render a price input field per `variant-item` instead of having a single input field.)

One way to synchronize a value with multiple child components, and assuming you are using a version of Vue >= 2.3 and < 3, is to use the [`.sync` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier).

Your parent component - the one that references the `variants` Array - would have a new data property for `variantPrice`. Here is an example where the parent is the root Vue component:

```
new Vue({
    components: {
        variantItem: VariantItem
    },
    data() {
        return {
            variantPrice: 0,
            variants: [
                {
                    inputName: 'VariantOne'
                },
                {
                    inputName: 'VariantTwo'
                }
            ]
        };
    },
    el: "#App"
});
```

The template of the parent (root) would pass `variantPrice` as a prop to each `variant-item` instance using the `.sync` modifier which will bind the value of `variantPrice` to the `update:variantPrice` event emitted by the child. The template would look like:

```
<div id="App">
    <variant-item v-for="(variant, index) in variants" :key="index" :variant="variant" :variant-price.sync="variantPrice"></variant-item>
</div>
```

Next, we must ensure that our VariantItem component takes a `variantPrice` as a prop and emits the `update:variantPrice` event when the input field is modified by the user:

```
const VariantItem = Vue.component('variant-item', {
    methods: {
        onVariantPriceInput(event) {
            this.$emit('update:variantPrice', Number(event.target.value));
        }
    },
    props: {
        variant: {
            required: true,
            type: Object
        },
        variantPrice: {
            required: true,
            type: Number
        }
    },
    template: '#VariantItemTemplate'
});
```

The template for this component would become:

```
<div>
    <label :for="variant.inputName">{{ variant.inputName }}</label>
    <input :id="variant.inputName" :name="variant.inputName" :value="variantPrice" @input="onVariantPriceInput" type="number">
</div>
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/q5f6so3y/) for your reference.

Comment: hey thanks man thats a lot of help sorry i missed the answer to accept it

Comment: actually your answer is right and i saw that working in fiddle i changed that according to my code but this is not working there for the sake of the guide i added the whole file so you can maybe find and tell me where is the problem cause i really cant solve this part thanks in advance

Comment: You have added so much code that I do not know where to begin. I think you need to narrow-down your problem.